# "Would you have any apple or cake?" Is this accepted in American English?

Tags: grammaticality, questions

A student wrote the following :

> Would you have any apple or cake?

A teacher from the UK recommends :

> Would you like to have an apple or a piece of cake?

I wish to check if the original question "Would you have any apple or cake?" can be accepted as grammatically correct in the US.

Comment: It is grammatically well-formed and meaningful (mostly--*apple* isn't ordinarily used as a mass noun), but it doesn't mean what you seem to intend: it's a polite way of asking whether your hearer actually **has** apple or cake (typically whether a shop or restaurant offers these goods), not whether they would **like to have** apple or cake to consume.

Comment: @StoneyB thanks for the detailed and very interesting analysis. Didn't expect the question can be used to query a shop or a restaurant.

Comment: ImagIne you’re at an icecream shop with many exotic flavors.  “I’ll have pistachio please. “ “Sorry we’re out of pistachio” “Would you have any apple or cake?” “We’re out of apple, but we do have cake.” “Ok, I’ll have a double in a sugar cone.”

Comment: @Jim in the case of an ice-cream shop, how do you compare it with : "Do you have any apple or cake (favor)?"  My guess is using "would" is more polite ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't mean the same thing. Each is meaningful.

1. The first asks whether you would like some apple (e.g., some pieces of apple, not "*an apple*") or some cake.  A more usual way to ask this would use *some*, not *any*, but *any* here suggests that you might already have replied negatively to some previous offer of food.

   Using *any* here is like asking, "*You say you're not hungry, but are you sure you would not care for some apple or some cake?*" IOW, *any* is typically used in a negative sentence: "*Don't you want any cake?*" Using it in the way you did is a way of hinting at this negativeness without being explicitly negative.

   Note that this use of *any* is not common. If coming from a non-native speaker it is likely to be understood as a mistaken attempt to say *some apple or some cake*.
2. The second asks whether you would like to have a (whole) apple or a piece of cake. Having a piece of cake is equivalent to having some cake, but having an apple is not equivalent to having some apple.